# How to upgrade Debian from buster to bookworm?

Tags: debian

What is the recommended way to upgrade Debian from buster to bookworm on an amd64 architecture ? Where can I find further information ?

Comment: 1st Google result: https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/update-upgrade-debian-11-to-debian-12-bookworm/

Comment: That google result is for Debian 11 -> Debian 12. Not what OP asked.

For an answer:
1) Upgrade from Debian 10 -> Debian 11. Follow the official instructions here: https://www.debian.org/releases/oldstable/amd64/release-notes/ch-upgrading.html

2) Upgrade from Debian 11 -> Debian 12. Follow the official instructions here: https://www.debian.org/releases/stable/amd64/release-notes/ch-upgrading.html

Please note that the instructions are long, and quite different.

Comment: It is possible, but you will likely encounter an issue with libcrypt. See https://www.debian.org/releases/bookworm/amd64/release-notes/ch-information.en.html#libcrypt-upgrade-from-buster for a solution.

Answer (score 2):

The regular Debian update process:

1. Install all outstanding required updates
2. Clean the system (no held packages, preferably no other repositories than debian, no leftover config files...)
3. Update your `sources.list` file with the next codename
4. Run `apt full-upgrade` and hope for the best
5. Reboot, check everything is running as expected or does after fixing issues

Repeat steps 3 to 5 until you have reached Debian Bookworm.

More details on these steps can be found by checking the [official Debian docs](https://www.debian.org/releases/bookworm/amd64/release-notes/ch-upgrading.en.html#upgrade-to-debian-oldrelease).

Comment: just never "jump" the steps of one major at a time, else.... you'll be ready for library problems